# Is the new 2015 Macbook Pro slower than my mid-2012 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, performance

I'm looking into buying a new MacBook Pro. The Mid 2012 model I have from work has a CPU with a clock speed of 2.9GHz:

[image: my model]

Compared to the models available in Apple's site, which have slower or equal clock speed:
[image]

Have I time travelled?

Comment: Keep in mind that a greater clock speed doesn't always guarantee a faster processor. It's a good standard, but there are other variables.

Comment: Short and exactly to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing in Apple website are the newer models with newer Intel processors. Your 2012 MBP model have a 22nm Core i7 "Ivy Bridge" Processor. The newer 2015 MBPs have 14nm "Broadwell" processor. If you compare the Geekench test, the 2015 i5 version outperforms your i7 2012 model. Clock speed does not matter, especially when you are comparing processors generations apart. the newer processors are more efficient and capable. For complete information and comparison, visit the links below.

[2012 MacBook Pro 13"](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.9-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html)

[Macs released in 2015](http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2015.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade the processors to be higher than 2.7GHz. At the customization page, you can also select options with blazing fast Turbo Boost speeds. 15-inch offers quad-core configurations as well.

Answer (score 1):

Over the last years the speed, in terms of work frequency, has a relatively modest increase.

[image]

So I guess Apple prefer provide better performance in other field (e.g., display, RAM, SSD, etc) instead of processor only.

---

Anyway, you can also ask for higher performance. For a good comparison, it would be nice to know the price your company paid in the 2012 for that machine.